# MySQL query on timestamp < 1 stops working after migration

Tags: php, mysql

I have migrated my XAMPP server from one laptop to the other (new one). 
I had a XAMPP 64 bit version on my old laptop and I have installed a 32 bit version on my new one.

After the migration, I couldn't get any `pages` data out of some tables.
After debugging, it appears the following query stopped working:

```
SELECT * FROM `pages` WHERE f_site_id = '1' AND deactivation_date < 1;
```

I initialize the deactivation_date field with the value: `0000-00-00 00:00:00`.

After changing the query from the above to the following:

```
SELECT * FROM `pages` WHERE f_site_id = '1' AND deactivation_date = '0000-00-00';
```

It seems to be working fine again.

Can anyone explain to my why the above occurred?
There are more places where I have a query that checks on a `timestamp < 1` and before I replace all the queries, I'd like to know why this happens.

**EDIT**
And is the last query the correct way to check for an empty timestamp?

Comment: Why would anyone expect a comparison between a date and an integer to return anything meaningful?  Your second version is correct.

Comment: I understand your reasoning. But I am trying to understand why it worked fine at first.

Comment: Probably due to the different mysql versions (64-bit and 32-bit have different versions on XAMPP I think) handling dates differently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't mention your old and new MySQL versions, so it's hard to pin this down exactly.

Older versions of MySQL had SQL strict mode, and [NO_ZERO_IN_DATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_no_zero_in_date) mode, disabled. So, casting a small integer as a `DATE` would generate a valid, if very early date.

Later versions won't do that. When you try to cast a small integer as a `DATE`, newer MySQL yields `NULL`.  And, `anything < NULL` yields false.

I think that's what happened to you. As time goes by the MySQL and MariaDB teams are steadily trying to get rid of datatype sloppiness.

Comment: Thank you for explaining this to me :D